# Rails 4 testing user initialization is always blank

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, unit-testing, tdd

Hey I have a test that looks like this

```
test 'create account' do
    if User.create(email: 'me@test.com', password: 'blahblah')
        assert true
    else
        assert User.msg
    end
end
```

But when I try to run it I'm getting an error message like this:

```
  1) Error:
UserTest#test_create_account:
ActiveRecord::RecordNotUnique: PG::UniqueViolation: ERROR:  duplicate key value violates unique constraint "index_users_on_email"
DETAIL:  Key (email)=() already exists.
: INSERT INTO "users" ("created_at", "updated_at", "id") VALUES ('2013-10-16 21:59:54', '2013-10-16 21:59:54', 298486374)
```

This looks to me as though I hadn't initialized email, but as I understand this should be initialized with my create above. I'm using strong params so I don't have any attr_accessable enabled and I can run this through. Does anyone know what could be causing this? If you want any more information let me know.

Comment: You definitely have a unique validation on your email attribute. This is raising an error as me@test.com has already been created with another user and/or is saved in your database. If you change the email parameter do you get the same error? what if you run it twice?

Comment: @JeremyS Thanks for the help! I Tried changing it and even with something completely unique I get the same exact error. If you look at the SQL it looks like only created_at, update_at, and id are being inserted

Comment: try `email: "#{SecureRandom.uuid}@test.com"`

Comment: AHAH! I got it. Rails auto added blank fixtures when I generated the scaffold. This was showing up as an error inside of my test for whatever reason. (shouldn't that show up separately?) Thank you so much for your help.

Comment: That will be helpful in the future, thanks for posting it!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This was caused by the automatically generated fixtures from the rails scaffolding. For whatever reason this shows up inside of the tests rather than in its own section. When I fixed the fixtures this error stopped appearing.

Comment: Hi @lethjakman, I am using factory_girls not fixtures then also its giving me same issue. Any idea?

Comment: Hey, I know this is a bit late but I figured better late than never, right? Double check to make sure that factory girl isn't generating a fixture for you anyways, and make sure your factory doesn't fail a unique validation on the database side. Those are the two issues that I know of that can cause this error.

Answer (score 0):

If you receive a PostgreSQL unique key violation error message, perhaps your primary key index is out of sync, e.g. after populating the database.

Use `ActiveRecord::Base.connection.reset_pk_sequence!('users')`
to bring the primary key index for the User table in sync again.